deploy a react.js site with data .json file in netlify
I have a react.js QuizApp project with question json file in data folder. I try to deploy that in Netlify site,but in it's demo when it is deployed, data don't load. It's demo works as long as, Npm run server command in Vscode is running. How can I deploy it in Netlify? Is there any way?
Here is my project structure.
Would you please guide me.
thank you
